# Missing main.server.ts and app.server.module.ts when installing Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-universal

I am trying to install Angular Universal using the following command as stated in the documentation:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

It creates the files server.ts but does not create main.server.ts and app.server.module.ts. I'm not too sure what's wrong but my package.json, angular version and tsconfig.server is the following:

package.json (shortened)

```
 "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.1",
        "@angular/common": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/material": "^13.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-server": "~13.2.1",
        "@angular/router": "~13.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~1.2.36",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.0.2",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "firebase": "^9.6.6",
        "leo-profanity": "^1.5.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~13.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.1",
        "@nguniversal/builders": "^13.0.2",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
        "eslint": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
        "typescript": "~4.5.5"
      }
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2019",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Version

[image: Versions:]

Comment: Does your `angular.json` contain the `architect:server` section? If yes, what's the value of the `options:main` field?

Comment: @Pieterjan The main field states 'server.ts'

Comment: True, I forgot about that. For asp.net core we have to replace it with [`src/main.server.ts`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.server.ts) but that’s the one you're missing ofc. What backend stack are you using? ASP.NET Core?